# Proof check: Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} (x^2+3) = 4$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$ s.t. $x \mapsto x^2+3$. Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} (x^2+3) = 4$.

This means that, for any $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_{0+}$, there exists a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}_{0+}$ s.t. $|x-1| \lt \delta \rightarrow |(x^2+3)-4| \lt \epsilon$.
Notice that $|(x^2 + 3) -4| = |x-1||x+1|$, and that   $(4-\epsilon, 4+\epsilon)$ and $(1-\delta, 1+\delta)$ are the $\epsilon, \delta$ neighborhoods.

**Proof.** Since the function is exponential, we know the distance $2|f^{-1}(4)-f^{-1}(4+\epsilon)|$ will be smaller than the distance $2|f^{-1}(4)-f^{-1}(\epsilon- 4)|$. Therefore, $\delta$ such that $f(\delta + 1) = 4+\epsilon$ will be smaller than $\delta$ such that $f(\delta - 1) = 4 - \epsilon$.

Let $(1+\delta)^2+3 = 4 + \epsilon$. Then, $\delta(2+\delta) = \epsilon$, which implies $|x-1|(2+|x-1|) \lt \epsilon$.
Either $|x-1|$ is greater than $|x+1|$, or its maximum difference is 2. Therefore, $|x-1||x+1| \lt \epsilon$. $\blacksquare$

Since I'm a beginner at analysis, I feel like there are some implicit assumptions here, if the proof is not simply plain wrong. Would anyone have feedback, either to see if it is true, or where I could strengthen the argument?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: a second attempt with the same method is made in [Proof writing: Prove that $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} (x^2+3) = 4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4117105/proof-writing-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to-1-x23-4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is not ok. First of all, you start with

> Since the function is exponential

which is false. The function is not exponential.

---

Second, you say

> we know the distance $2|f^{-1}(4)-f^{-1}(4+\epsilon)|$ will be

which is not OK because you didn't yet prove that $f^{-1}$ exists. In fact, it doesn't because $f$ is not a bijective function.

---

Third, you state that

> we know the distance $2|f^{-1}(4)-f^{-1}(4+\epsilon)|$ will be smaller than the distance $2|f^{-1}(4)-f^{-1}(\epsilon- 4)|$

without any kind of proof.

---

Next, you say

> Let $(1+\delta)^2+3 = 4 + \epsilon$

but you haven't even proven that a value of $\delta$ that satisfies this equality **exists**.

Comment: quick question: if I define $\delta$ to satisfy $(1+\delta)^2 + 3 = 4 + \epsilon$, do I have to prove it actually exists?

Comment: @shintuku $\delta$ is, in that case, a solution to a quadratic equation. So you can solve that equation. Just be sure to also check that the solution is *positive*. Also, try to be clever with solving the equation. Don't expand all the factors and then calculate the discriminant. Rather, first simplify the equation, then notice you get $(1+\delta)^2=1+\epsilon$, and take the square root of that (being careful with the signs, of course).